# DryIoc cannot resolve my boolean instance?

Tags: dryioc

I try to register a class which constructor requires a few string, a ILog and a bool. All in my container is registered as a singleton (set as the default Reuse).

But whenever I try to get an instance of that class `container.Resolve<AzmanAccess>()`, an exception gets thrown.

> Unable to resolve Boolean as parameter "accessAll"  in
>   Company.Common.Util.Authentication.AzmanAccess:
>   Company.Common.Util.Authentication.IAzmanAccess
>   {RequiredServiceType=Company.Common.Util.Authentication.AzmanAccess}
>   as parameter "azmanAccess"  in
>   Company.Common.Util.Authentication.AzmanCustomAccess:
>   Company.Common.Util.Authentication.IAccess as parameter "access"  in
>   Company.Common.Util.Authentication.User:
>   Company.Common.Util.Authentication.IUser Where CurrentScope: null  and
>   ResolutionScope: null  and Found registrations:  skipAuthz,{ID=53,
>   ImplType=Boolean, Reuse=SingletonReuse {Lifespan=1000}}} 
>   System.Object,{ID=25, ImplType=Boolean, Reuse=SingletonReuse
>   {Lifespan=1000}}}

I register my class like this:

```
        container.RegisterInstance(_accessAll, serviceKey: AccessAll);
        container.RegisterInstance(_activeDirectoryDomain, serviceKey: ActiveDirectoryDomain);
        container.RegisterInstance(_azmanConnString, serviceKey: AzmanConnString);
        container.RegisterInstance(_azmanStore, serviceKey: AzmanStore);
        container.Register(Made.Of(() => new AzmanAccess(
                Arg.Of<bool>(AccessAll),
                Arg.Of<ILog>(),
                Arg.Of<string>(ActiveDirectoryDomain),
                Arg.Of<string>(AzmanConnString),
                Arg.Of<string>(AzmanStore)
            )));
```

and the constructor is:

```
    public AzmanAccess(bool accessAll, ILog logger, string activeDirectoryDomain, string azmanConnString, string azmanStore)
```

Where servicekeys (AccessAll, ...) are unique (tried with objects, then string).

What's going wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the service key AccessAll? I reproduced your case with the string key and it worked.

Comment: @dadhi Did you try with "new object()" for the other service key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused by [the bug in DryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/issues/278/argof-does-not-recognize-service-key-of): `Arg.Of` does not recognize service key of non-primitive type.

Until bug is fixed the workaround is to change `object` service key to e.g. `string`, `Enum type`, or `int`.

**Update:**
The fix is available in [DryIoc v2.4.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll/).